# How to use webstorage?

Tags: javascript

I want to use webstorage to save and get some value.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Note app</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script src="JS/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="JS/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveNote() {
    localStorage.setItem("note", jQuery("#note").val());


function retrieveNote() {
    jQuery('#note').val(localStorage.getItem("note"));

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"id="Home">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Note app</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<textarea type="text" id="note" class="input-inline"></textarea>
<a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="saveNote()" style="width:120px;margin:auto">Save note</a>
<a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="retrieveNote()" style="width:150px;margin:auto">Retrieve note</a>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h1>test</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is that nothing is going when I click retrieve/save button. What should I do to make this buttons work?
I am testing it in http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_start

Comment: The first function isn't closed. You should have an error on the javascript console I think.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but had a couple of errors. first you needed to close your first function.

See working code below.

```
<script>
 function saveNote() {
    localStorage.setItem("note", jQuery("#note").val());
}

function retrieveNote() {
    jQuery('#noteRetrieve').text(localStorage.getItem("note"));
}
</script>
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Note app</h1>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <textarea type="text" id="note" class="input-inline"></textarea>
    <div id="noteRetrieve"></div>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="saveNote()" style="width:120px;margin:auto">Save note</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="retrieveNote()" style="width:150px;margin:auto">Retrieve note</a>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I launch this code in Firefox or this validator (link in first post) these buttons still do not do anything.

Comment: @pilovsky works for me when you add the code to the link in the first post. copy both the javascript and html and replace the code in the link in between the body tags.

Comment: yes I did it, I see two buttons and text field. So let me ask you, what happens if you click "retrieve button" ?

Comment: when you click the retrieve button it gets the item from local storage and places it as the text in the div with the id `retrieveText`

Comment: it seems clear but why it does not display anything?
here are my steps:
1. Put 'ABC" in text field
2. click save button
3. remove 'ABC' from text field
4. click retrieve button
and it shows nothing, I expected it to dislay ABC

Comment: @pilovsky i cant see the code you pasted, but it shows for me. Are you sure you are adding the code I provided correctly?

Comment: yes totally. I just edited my previous comment, please take a look

Comment: @pilovsky works for me! did you click on `Save Note`?

Comment: Yes I did. I'm taking the steps as I described previously. So you are saying that you are taking the same four steps; put some ABC text > click save> remove that ABC text> click retrieve > you see ABC in this field?

Comment: if you open the console do you get any errors? have you placed the `script` code above the `html`?

Comment: damn, I missed the line:  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">, I checked console as you said, and there was: "jQuery is not defined", and  I found that I need to include some library ,thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your functions should be closed.
It should have proper start { and proper end }.

Other than that it should work fine.
You can read more about webstorage [here](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/session-storage-local-storage-how-webstorage.html).